# My hash rate is low and volatile and my wattage is high?

Tags: mining, gpu-mining, hashrate, mining-hardware, mining-profitability

I have 3 Vegas (1 Vega 56 flashed, 1 Vega 56 not flashed, 1 Vega 64) My 64 can run at 2035 h/s but requires +50 max power and thus takes around 300 watt but is stable. My other two cards are completely wild. They both have power play tables on them yet they are more volatile than anything. I will start the night with 5600 h/s at 850 watt and end with 5150 h/s at 740 watt. I have tried doing power play on my Vega 64 yet every time I do it turns the GPU off after restart. This whole system is fucked up and I have no idea what the hell to do. I already have OverdriveNTool to try to stabilize but to no avail. My other Vega 56 if you were wondering is a msi air boost and there is no way to flash it so that's why it isn't flashed. How do I fix it one problem at a time?

Answer (score 1):

Take a deep breath.

Use restore points.

Follow the guide provided by CircusDad at [vega.miningguides](http://vega.miningguides.com/).
You should be able to run your Vegas at much lower than 300W and keep stability.